# When deploying a stream with MongoDB Sink I got a MappingException "Couldn't find PersistentEntity for type class [B!"

Tags: spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-dataflow

I'm facing this problem when I'm trying to use the MongoDB Sink app starter with an information read by a JDBC source:

```
MappingException: Couldn't find PersistentEntity for type class [B!
```

Class `[B`! means that is a `byte[]`. I printed in a log and this is the JSON of the object. Is this a bug? The other sinks are working perfectly.

I'm using **Spring Cloud Data Flow 1.6.3** in local deployment.
The app starters are in **Darwin.SR1** version.

And this is the **stream definition:**

```
jdbc --password='mypass' --query='SELECT id, name FROM mytable WHERE imported = false' --max-rows-per-poll=1000 --update='UPDATE mytable SET imported = true WHERE id in (:id)' --fixed-delay=30 --time-unit=SECONDS --driver-class-name=org.postgresql.Driver --url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/mydatabase --username=postgres | mongodb --database=main --port=27017 --host=localhost --collection=mycollection --uri=mongodb://localhost/main
```

**Full Stacktrace:**

```
org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.exception.ListenerExecutionFailedException: Listener threw exception
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.wrapToListenerExecutionFailedExceptionIfNeeded(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1506) ~[spring-rabbit-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doInvokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1417) ~[spring-rabbit-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.actualInvokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1337) ~[spring-rabbit-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.invokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1324) ~[spring-rabbit-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.executeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1303) ~[spring-rabbit-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.doReceiveAndExecute(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:817) [spring-rabbit-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.receiveAndExecute(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:801) [spring-rabbit-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.access$700(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:77) [spring-rabbit-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageProcessingConsumer.run(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:1042) [spring-rabbit-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.4.RELEASE]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_73]
Caused by: org.springframework.messaging.MessageDeliveryException: failed to send Message to channel 'SystemOutAndSink.systemOutProcessor.SystemOutAndSink.errors'; nested exception is org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.exception.ListenerExecutionFailedException: Retry Policy Exhausted
    at org.springframework.integration.support.utils.IntegrationUtils.wrapInDeliveryExceptionIfNecessary(IntegrationUtils.java:163) ~[spring-integration-core-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:475) ~[spring-integration-core-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:394) ~[spring-integration-core-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:181) ~[spring-messaging-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:160) ~[spring-messaging-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:47) ~[spring-messaging-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.send(AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.java:108) ~[spring-messaging-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.send(AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.java:98) ~[spring-messaging-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.support.ErrorMessagePublisher.publish(ErrorMessagePublisher.java:164) ~[spring-integration-core-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.advice.ErrorMessageSendingRecoverer.recover(ErrorMessageSendingRecoverer.java:83) ~[spring-integration-core-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.retry.support.RetryTemplate.handleRetryExhausted(RetryTemplate.java:512) ~[spring-retry-1.2.2.RELEASE.jar!/:na]
    at org.springframework.retry.support.RetryTemplate.doExecute(RetryTemplate.java:351) ~[spring-retry-1.2.2.RELEASE.jar!/:na]
    at org.springframework.retry.support.RetryTemplate.execute(RetryTemplate.java:180) ~[spring-retry-1.2.2.RELEASE.jar!/:na]
    at org.springframework.integration.amqp.inbound.AmqpInboundChannelAdapter$Listener.onMessage(AmqpInboundChannelAdapter.java:211) ~[spring-integration-amqp-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doInvokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1414) ~[spring-rabbit-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.4.RELEASE]
    ... 8 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.exception.ListenerExecutionFailedException: Retry Policy Exhausted
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.retry.RejectAndDontRequeueRecoverer.recover(RejectAndDontRequeueRecoverer.java:45) ~[spring-rabbit-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.rabbit.RabbitMessageChannelBinder$3.handleMessage(RabbitMessageChannelBinder.java:513) ~[spring-cloud-stream-binder-rabbit-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.BroadcastingDispatcher.invokeHandler(BroadcastingDispatcher.java:224) ~[spring-integration-core-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.BroadcastingDispatcher.dispatch(BroadcastingDispatcher.java:180) ~[spring-integration-core-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractSubscribableChannel.doSend(AbstractSubscribableChannel.java:73) ~[spring-integration-core-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:445) ~[spring-integration-core-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    ... 21 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.amqp.AmqpRejectAndDontRequeueException: org.springframework.messaging.MessageHandlingException: error occurred in message handler [mongoDbSinkMessageHandler]; nested exception is org.springframework.data.mapping.MappingException: Couldn't find PersistentEntity for type class [B!, failedMessage=GenericMessage [payload=byte[26], headers={amqp_receivedDeliveryMode=PERSISTENT, sequenceNumber=1, amqp_receivedExchange=SystemOutAndSink.systemOutProcessor, amqp_deliveryTag=1, sequenceSize=1, deliveryAttempt=3, amqp_consumerQueue=SystemOutAndSink.systemOutProcessor.SystemOutAndSink, amqp_redelivered=false, amqp_receivedRoutingKey=SystemOutAndSink.systemOutProcessor, correlationId=33566e38-0f55-25be-40d6-5ef68ca496b2, id=e636d851-dc51-dbc3-99d6-3705ef71db59, amqp_consumerTag=amq.ctag-4DTfbrWGYdijPJZnyJzGpQ, contentType=application/json, timestamp=1538314765609}]
    ... 27 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.messaging.MessageHandlingException: error occurred in message handler [mongoDbSinkMessageHandler]; nested exception is org.springframework.data.mapping.MappingException: Couldn't find PersistentEntity for type class [B!
    at org.springframework.integration.support.utils.IntegrationUtils.wrapInHandlingExceptionIfNecessary(IntegrationUtils.java:184) ~[spring-integration-core-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:175) ~[spring-integration-core-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.ReplyProducingMessageHandlerWrapper.handleRequestMessage(ReplyProducingMessageHandlerWrapper.java:47) ~[spring-integration-core-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:109) ~[spring-integration-core-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:158) ~[spring-integration-core-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.AbstractDispatcher.tryOptimizedDispatch(AbstractDispatcher.java:116) ~[spring-integration-core-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.doDispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:132) ~[spring-integration-core-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.dispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:105) ~[spring-integration-core-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractSubscribableChannel.doSend(AbstractSubscribableChannel.java:73) ~[spring-integration-core-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:445) ~[spring-integration-core-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:394) ~[spring-integration-core-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:181) ~[spring-messaging-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:160) ~[spring-messaging-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:47) ~[spring-messaging-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.send(AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.java:108) ~[spring-messaging-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.MessageProducerSupport.sendMessage(MessageProducerSupport.java:203) ~[spring-integration-core-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.amqp.inbound.AmqpInboundChannelAdapter.access$1100(AmqpInboundChannelAdapter.java:60) ~[spring-integration-amqp-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.amqp.inbound.AmqpInboundChannelAdapter$Listener.lambda$onMessage$0(AmqpInboundChannelAdapter.java:214) ~[spring-integration-amqp-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.retry.support.RetryTemplate.doExecute(RetryTemplate.java:287) ~[spring-retry-1.2.2.RELEASE.jar!/:na]
    ... 11 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.data.mapping.MappingException: Couldn't find PersistentEntity for type class [B!
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.MappingContext.getRequiredPersistentEntity(MappingContext.java:76) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.8.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.writeInternal(MappingMongoConverter.java:435) ~[spring-data-mongodb-2.0.8.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.write(MappingMongoConverter.java:391) ~[spring-data-mongodb-2.0.8.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.write(MappingMongoConverter.java:86) ~[spring-data-mongodb-2.0.8.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.toDocument(MongoTemplate.java:1070) ~[spring-data-mongodb-2.0.8.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.doSave(MongoTemplate.java:1253) ~[spring-data-mongodb-2.0.8.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.save(MongoTemplate.java:1201) ~[spring-data-mongodb-2.0.8.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.mongodb.outbound.MongoDbStoringMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(MongoDbStoringMessageHandler.java:124) ~[spring-integration-mongodb-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:158) ~[spring-integration-core-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    ... 28 common frames omitted
```

Comment: Hi. This seems like an incomplete report. Could you please edit the post and update the description with the versions in use, and as well, the stream definition(s)? See [wiki](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-dataflow#reporting-issues) for more details.

Comment: Thanks, @SabbyAnandan, it's updated.

Comment: How does ti work if you specify an `--inputType=application/json` on the `mongodb` application definition? http://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-dataflow/docs/1.6.3.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#passing_content_type_properties

Comment: @ArtemBilan The same error appears after put the --inputType=application/json parameter on the mongodb app definition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as `MongoTemplate.save()` (essentially the `mappingContext.getPersistentEntity(type)`) doesn't support the simple `byte[]` (or similar `ByteBuffer` or just `InputStream`), we don't have choice unless to convert inbound `byte[]` into the `String` to make it work.

So, for this purpose you need to write a simple jar with the auto-configuration and bean like this:

```
@Bean
@GlobalChannelInterceptor(patterns = Sink.INPUT)
public ChannelInterceptor bytesToStringChannelInterceptor() {
    return new ChannelInterceptor() {

        @Override
        public Message<?> preSend(Message<?> message, MessageChannel channel) {
            if (message.getPayload() instanceof byte[]) {
                String contentType = message.getHeaders().containsKey(MessageHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE)
                        ? message.getHeaders().get(MessageHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE).toString()
                        : BindingProperties.DEFAULT_CONTENT_TYPE.toString();
                if (contentType.contains("text") ||
                        contentType.contains("json") ||
                        contentType.contains("x-spring-tuple")) {

                    return new MutableMessage<>(new String(((byte[]) message.getPayload())), message.getHeaders());
                }
            }
            return message;

        }
    };
}
```

To force a `byte[]` inbound to be converted to the supported `String` on the `MongoTemplate`.

Feel free to raise an issue against MongoDB App Starter to include this feature into the box.

Comment: Thanks, @Artem Bilan, I've concluded that the streaming between the two applications serializes the JSON String as a byte[]. I've added a processor between the source and the MongoDB Sink just to enforce the JSON String serialization, and the outcome still the same. So, as the serialization as a byte[] is a default behavior, raise an issue should be a good enhancement for the product.

Comment: Well, it is still `byte[]` on the wire, so your additional processor doesn't matter. On the `sink` level we check for the target type and it is just plain `Message<?>` therefore we don't convert bytes from the wire. As we discussed the Spring Data MongoDB should support `byte[]` for sending as as well `ByteBuffer` and `InputStream`. Would be great to raise an issue there as  well!

Comment: We are going to fix this in the MongoDB Sink meanwhile: https://github.com/spring-cloud-stream-app-starters/mongodb/issues/6

Comment: Great @Artem Bilan! I appreciate your fast solution to this problem. I'll accept your answer, but for future users with this problem, I strongly recommend to update the Mongodb Sink app to Darwin.SR2 or above version.